# Linux restores windows on reboot

Tags: linux, memory, crash, reboot

A computer has been overloaded with too many windows/programs at once which leads to crash.  Unfortunately the system is configured (somehow) to reload all of these windows/programs on reboot, does anyone know how to get around this and have a clean boot? Thank you..

Comment: That depends on how they're being started. Through your init system? If so, which init are you using? Or through cron?

Comment: This question is more suitable for superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log into a terminal (hit ALT+CTRL+F1) and edit/remove your session file (dependent on desktop environment).
2. Better aks for help on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)